# Bootstrap 4 Tab On Click Does not Fill Content

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, tabs, containers

I have a bootstrap row with 4 columns (col-lg-3). Within one of the columns is a tab-content element. When the page renders, the javascript populates and fills the card correctly, however, when I click on the next tab the content overflows the box and does not render within the div width at all.

I have tried adding style="width:200px" to any and all of the div containers within this column, but none of them will yield when I click the tab.

[image]

Tab Content Code:

```
            <div class="col-lg-3 align-items-stretch">
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="card-header bg-14">
                            <h2><?php echo $lang_top_airlines ?></h2>
                        </div>
                            <div class="card-body">


                            <div class="tab-content" id="nav-TopAirlines" style="width:250px">

                                    <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="nav-airlines-flights" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-airline-flights">
                                        <?php 
                                            $path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
                                            $path .= "/includes/connections/mysqli.php";
                                            require($path);

                                            $sql = "SELECT count(*) as countLVM, lvm.luchtvaartmaatschappij AS naam, lvm.IATACode
                                                    FROM tbl_vluchtgegevens vg

                                                    LEFT JOIN tbl_luchtvaartmaatschappij lvm
                                                    ON vg.luchtvaartmaatschappij = lvm.luchtvaartmaatschappijID

                                                    WHERE vertrekdatum2 <=NOW()

                                                    GROUP BY lvm.luchtvaartmaatschappij
                                                    ORDER BY countLVM DESC
                                                    LIMIT 10";

                                            $dataAF = $link->query($sql);
                                            $dataPointsAF = array();

                                            if ($dataAF->num_rows > 0) {

                                                while($rowAF = $dataAF->fetch_assoc()) {
                                                     $pointAF = array("label" => $rowAF['IATACode'], "y" => $rowAF['countLVM'], "name"=> $rowAF['naam']);
                                                    array_push($dataPointsAF, $pointAF);
                                                }
                                            }
                                            $link->close();        

                                            ?>

                                            <div id="TopAirlinesFlights" style="width: 200px; height: 300px;"></div>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="nav-airlines-distance" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-airline-distance">
                                        <?php 
                                            $path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
                                            $path .= "/includes/connections/mysqli.php";
                                            require($path);

                                            $sql = "SELECT lvm.luchtvaartmaatschappij AS naam, lvm.IATACode, SUM(vr.afstand) as SumDistance
                                                    FROM tbl_vluchtgegevens vg

                                                    LEFT JOIN tbl_vliegroutes vr
                                                    ON vg.vertrekluchthaven = vr.vertrekID
                                                    AND vg.aankomstluchthaven = vr.aankomstID

                                                    LEFT JOIN tbl_luchtvaartmaatschappij lvm
                                                    ON vg.luchtvaartmaatschappij = lvm.luchtvaartmaatschappijID

                                                    WHERE vg.vertrekdatum2 <=NOW()

                                                    GROUP BY lvm.luchtvaartmaatschappij
                                                    ORDER BY SumDistance DESC
                                                    LIMIT 10;";

                                            $dataAirD = $link->query($sql);
                                            $dataPointsAirD = array();

                                            if ($dataAirD->num_rows > 0) {

                                                while($rowAirD = $dataAirD->fetch_assoc()) {
                                                    $pointAirD = array("label" => $rowAirD['IATACode'], "y" => $rowAirD['SumDistance'], "name"=> $rowAirD['naam']);
                                                    array_push($dataPointsAirD, $pointAirD);
                                                }
                                            }
                                            $link->close();        

                                            ?>


                                            <div id="TopAirlinesDistance" style="width: 200px; height: 300px;"></div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>



                                <nav>
                                    <div class="nav nav-fill nav-pills" id="nav-airline" role="tablist">
                                        <a class="nav-item nav-link active" role="tab" id="nav-airline-flights" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-airlines-flights" aria-controls="nav-airlines-flights" aria-selected="true"><i class="fas fa-plane-departure"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;by Flights</a>
                                        <a class="nav-item nav-link" role="tab" id="nav-airline-distance" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-airlines-distance" aria-controls="nav-airlines-distance" aria-selected="false">
                                            <i class="fas fa-map-marked-alt"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;by Distance</a>
                                    </div>
                                </nav>


                            </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Javascript Code (just in case I'm missing something here):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {

        CanvasJS.addColorSet("blueShades2",
                        [//colorSet Array
                            "#074b83",  
                            "#085a9d",  
                            "#0a69b7",
                            "#0b78d1",
                            "#0c87eb",
                            "#2196f3",
                            "#4daaf6",
                            "#79bff8",
                            "#a6d4fa",
                            "#d2eafd"
                        ]);

    var TopAirports = new CanvasJS.Chart("TopAirports", {
        zoomEnabled: false,
        axisX:{ 
            reversed:  true
            },
        animationEnabled: true,

        colorSet: "blueShades2",

        toolTip:{content: "{name}: {y}"},
        data: [{
            type: "bar",
            indexLabelFontSize: 14,
            indexLabel: "{y}",
            indexLabelPlacement: "outside",  
            indexLabelOrientation: "horizontal",
            dataPoints: <?php echo json_encode($dataPointsTA, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK); ?>
             }]
    });


    var TopAirlinesFlights = new CanvasJS.Chart("TopAirlinesFlights", {
        zoomEnabled: false,
        animationEnabled: true,
        colorSet: "blueShades2",
        axisX:{ 
            reversed:  true
            },
        toolTip:{content: "{name}: {y}"},
        data: [{
            type: "bar",
            indexLabelFontSize: 14,
            indexLabel: "{y}",
            indexLabelPlacement: "outside",  
            indexLabelOrientation: "horizontal",
            dataPoints: <?php echo json_encode($dataPointsAF, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK); ?>
             }]
    });


    var TopAirlinesDistance = new CanvasJS.Chart("TopAirlinesDistance", {
    zoomEnabled: false,
    animationEnabled: true,
    colorSet: "blueShades2",
    axisX:{ 
        reversed:  true
        },
    toolTip:{content: "{name}: {y}"},
    data: [{
        type: "bar",
        indexLabelFontSize: 14,
        indexLabel: "{y}",
        indexLabelPlacement: "outside",  
        indexLabelOrientation: "horizontal",
        dataPoints: <?php echo json_encode($dataPointsAirD, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK); ?>
         }]
});


    TopAirlinesFlights.render();
    TopAirports.render();
    TopAirlinesDistance.render();
    });


    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know the width will need to be 200px then you can set: max-width:200px.

You will need to use Media Queries though to keep adjusting the max-width value when the screen size changes to a bigger screen. If you don't then it will always stay at 200px.

Comment: unfortunately, even just setting max-width:200px, it does not fix it. Every time I click on that nav, the contents jump outside of the card div. . . hmmm.

Comment: Have you tried setting the width directly in CanvasJS.Chart?
https://canvasjs.com/docs/charts/chart-options/width/

Comment: interesting. I had not thought about that, but that worked exactly as expected. Thanks for the tip!